# Normed vector space : when and who?

Tags: topology

When does the concept of "normed vector space" emerge?

Who is the first mathematician to consider this setting?

Comment: The earliest use Google Books found for me was 1934; by 1950 it was common.

Comment: @kimchilover Could you please cite some reference, particularly for the rarity? So it would make a good answer.

Comment: @peterhsaysreinstateMonica  I will, but not today. Every time I check GB I get a different answer, and GB is so whimsical about dates. There is a 1940's Trans. AMS article using it; it's in Halmos's 1947 Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces.

Comment: I think the general consensus is that the idea of a normed space independently arose in the early 1920s by S. Banach, H. Hahn (following up on work by E. Helly), and N. Wiener. See pp. 66-68 of [*The development of function spaces with particular reference to their origins in integral equation theory*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41133253) (also [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00412288)) by Michael Bernkopf (1966). Also, google these names along with "history" and "functional analysis" and "norm".

Comment: My bad: I misread the Q to ask for the origin of the _term_, not the _concept_.

Comment: @kimchilover I am also interested by when the term appeared.

Comment: "Integration of Functions with Values in a Bananch Space" by
Garrett Birkhoff , Trans AMS, v.38 (1935), pp 357-358 starts out with "The central concern of this paper is the integration of functions with values in a complete normed vector space, or "Banach" space".  It cites papers by L.M. Graves in the 1926 TAMS, but they do not use the term.

Comment: And a 1934 Bulletin article uses NVS: https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1934-40-02/S0002-9904-1934-05807-5/S0002-9904-1934-05807-5.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good source for these types of questions is Miller's site [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/n.html). On the norms in vector spaces we find the following:

> "*On page 57 of his 1908 paper “Über die Auflösung linearer Gleichungen mit unendlich vielen Unbekannten,” Rendiconti del Circolo Matematico di Palermo, 25 (1908), Erhard Schmidt defines for a function A(x), x = 1, 2, 3 ..., which, he says in a footnote, can be regarded as a vector in an infinite-dimensional space, a positive quantity ||A||, the Euclidean norm, which he calls the length, and calls a vector “normirt,” if its length is equal to 1.*
>
> "*In 1921 Albert A. Bennett "Normalized Geometric Systems," Proc. National Acad. Sci. U.S.A. 7 p. 84: "The notion of norm or numerical value of a complex quantity, c = a + b√- 1, namely, |c| = √(a2 + b2), as it arises in algebra, has a more or less immediate generalization to more extensive matric systems."*"
>
> "*In 1922 S. Banach defined “la norme” for an abstract linear space in “Sur les opérations dans les ensembles abstraits et leur application aux équations integrales”, Fundamenta Mathematicae, 3, pp. 135-6. Among the examples (pp. 167-8) is $║\varphi║$ defined by $\sqrt[r]{\int_a^l|\varphi|^r\,dx}$.*"

As Dave Renfro mentioned in the comment, the theory of normed vector spaces was developed in the 1920-s by Banach, Hahn and Wiener (concrete functional spaces with a norm, without the name, were studied before that). Their use became a standard tool Banach's 1932 book [*Théorie des opérations linéaires* (Theory of Linear Operations, 1932)](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.493033), which flashed out the role of completeness and systematically developed the theory of linear operators on complete (Banach) spaces. Additional impulse was provided by [von Neumann's Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Foundations_of_Quantum_Mechanics) published the same year, which systematically utilized Hilbert spaces and operators on them.